# predicate for fetching an entities' assosicate entities where associate entity's certain attribute has a certain string value

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

i have catalogues and categories entities in my coredata

they have a many-to-many relationship

i want to fetch specific categories where field categoryStatus="active" and involved in catalogue.categories

what is the proper predicate ?

or without a fetch > catalogue.categories where categoryStatus=@"active"

c# equivelant of aCatalogue.categories.Where(c=>c.categoryStatus == "active")

### i try something like this but no luck

```
-(NSArray *) CategoryGetListWhereStatusActive4Catalogue:aCatalogue2DisplayCategories
{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"([catalogues containsObject:%@) AND (categoryStatus == %@)" , aCatalogue2DisplayCategories, @"active"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

return [self performFetch:fetchRequest withContextObject:context];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any predicate so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY catalogues == %@) AND (categoryStatus == %@)",
           aCatalogue, @"active"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(catalogues, $catalogues, $catalogues == %@).@count>0) AND (categoryStatus == %@)" , aCatalogue2DisplayCategories, @"active"];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY catalogues = %@) AND (categoryStatus == %@)" , aCatalogue2DisplayCategories, @"active"];
```

Comment: Isn't the second predicate exactly what I wrote? (And the first predicate is just a complicated way to achieve the identical result.)

Comment: Sorry didn't see yours.